# QGIS: How can I reproject multiple associated layers when improving the georeference of an ancient map?

Tags: qgis, georeferencing

If I add or move some georeferencing control points and re-georeference a map, then is there a way in which I can make the latest QGIS reproject the points/lines/polygons in associated layers automatically?

I georeferenced a 17th-century map, then digitized thousands of map elements (points, lines, polygons) in various additional layers.  Now I find myself wanting to add or move some georeferencing points to improve the location of features in parts of the map, which means that the corresponding digitized map elements (points, line vertexes, polygon vertexes) in other layers have to move, too.  I did this once by hand: re-georeference the map, then manually move all points/lines/polygons as needed.  This was a *lot* of work.  How can I have QGIS do most or all of that work?

Comment: To be honest your question is not really clear to me. So you so have a 17th century map that you vectorized and now you want to improve the georeferenced map and automatically update all the features you already made?

Comment: @GISGUILD: Correct.